# How to do a two different array results manipulation in angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

Here is a product Service response.

```
productServiceResponse = [
  {productOrderId:108898,productStatus:"C",productId:'4'},
  {productOrderId:108899,productStatus:"P",productId:'2'},
];
```

by using const value  currentProductStatus = "C";

In product Service response ,i need to find the current product and taken the product by using above constant value and taken the product id.

So here i did that .Here i have did the index of the current product instead of that need it in dynamicllay find out from the collection .

```
this.productServiceResponse[0].productStatus
```

// check the current product

```
  const ProductCode =
            this.productServiceResponse[0].productStatus ===
            this.currentProductStatus
              ? this.productServiceResponse[0].productId.toString()
              : null;
```

once get the current productId.

i have check it in another collection.

```
      productTypes =[
    {id: "1", name: "Laptop"},
    {id: "2", name: "Mobile"},
    {id: "3", name: "headphone"},
    {id: "4", name: "Cameras"}
      ];
```

from the product types collection , i have match the product id from the above result.

```
   this.currentProduct = this.productTypes.find(product=>product.id ===ProductCode).name;
```

final o/p becomes cameras.

I have got the o/p :but i need this query in single line filteration instead of two variables.

can any one refactor this.

Demo:[filter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjekuz)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss14hb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The result is wrong o/p should be camera and not both , because  productStatus is C  for product Id `{productOrderId:108898,productStatus:"C",productId:'4'}`

Comment: i gave you flexible solution where everything is mapped correctly. now you just pick up your index you need ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
this.productTypes.find(product=>
    product.id === productServiceResponse.find(psr=>psr.productStatus === this.currentProductStatus).productID
    ).name
```

Be advised I typed this in my cell phone [image: check this]

Comment: i have changed that to `this.productTypes.find(product => {
    product.id === this.productServiceResponse.find(psr=>psr.productStatus === this.currentProductStatus).map(x=>x.productID)
    }).map(x=>x.name);`  getting below error
  _this.productServiceResponse.find(...).map is not a function

Comment: sure, since `map` is being ran on an `object` and not `array` since `find` returns (first) `object` satisfying criteria given to it.

Comment: Just take the .map out of the code and leave it like .productId and .name I edited my answer like so

Comment: @deezig o/p is wrong in your code there is no check for currentProductStatus The result is wrong o/p should be camera and not both , because productStatus is C for product Id {productOrderId:108898,productStatus:"C",productId:'4'}

Comment: @Gabriel Lopez thanks man i have nested manipulation from your solution.keep support in stackoverflow

Comment: @MohamedSahir  My pleasure